# Custom component controller is not re-instantiated by a rerender?

Tags: visualforce-component, rerender

If I have a custom component contained within an outputPanel, and I rerender the outputPanel, does Salesforce re-instantiate the component controller and reload its data?  It looks like it doesn't.

Details: the custom component is displaying related records.  The parent VF page is deleting one of the records and I want to refresh the displayed list.  Right now I have to do a full page reload since rerender is not changing anything.

Thanks
David

Comment: There's a discussion of communicating between main controller and component controller here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50008/passing-data-from-page-controller-to-component-controller
You should be able to use this technique to have the main controller pass a message to the component, telling it to refresh its list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors are only called when the page is first loaded. Odds are, you'll want to expose an actionFunction in the component and call that function as the oncomplete function from your reRender. Alternatively, you could write a getter in the component's controller, but this may cause unnecessary queries.